# How to do a `getOrWaitUntilNonEmpty` as a single liner?

Tags: scala, retry-logic

I have a high-level code structure that looks like this:

```
val block: (=> Option[Seq[String]]) = ...
val matches = block().get.toArray
```

The problem is that this code may fail i.e. `.get` being `None` depending on the time e.g. I'm page-**scraping** Google too often, then I'd wait and retry ...

I can do the waiting like this i.e. random waits between 11-16s:

```
val random = new Random()
Thread.sleep((11000 * random.nextFloat() + 6000).ceil.toInt)
```

What would be an elegant single-liner way to [waiting] loop until the result of executing `block` isn't empty? Something like:

```
val timeInMillis = (11000 * random.nextFloat() + 6000).ceil.toInt
block().getOrWaitUntilNonEmpty(timeInMillis).toArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`softwaremill/retry`](https://github.com/softwaremill/retry) like so

```
retry.Pause(max = 10, Defaults.delay)(odelay.Timer.default) {
  block
}
```

with dependencies

```
"com.softwaremill.retry"  %% "retry"       % "0.3.2"
"com.softwaremill.odelay" %% "odelay-core" % "0.3.0"
```