# Retry with resilience4j doesn't work with some exceptions

Tags: java, scala, resilience4j

I am using the resilience4j library to retry some code, I have the following code below, I expect it to run 4 times. If I throw IllegalArgumentException it works but if I throw ConnectException it doesn't.

```
object Test extends App {

  val retryConf = RetryConfig.custom()
    .maxAttempts(4)
    .retryOnException(_ => true)
    //.retryExceptions(classOf[ConnectException])
    .build
  val retryRegistry = RetryRegistry.of(retryConf)
  val retryConfig = retryRegistry.retry("test", retryConf)
  val supplier: Supplier[Unit] = () => {
    println("Run")
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test")
    //throw new ConnectException("Test")
  }

  val decoratedSupplier = Decorators.ofSupplier(supplier).withRetry(retryConfig).get()
}
```

I expected that retry to retry on all exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating [decorated supplier](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/438bf75c853567f54b7abda968028b15895105d5/resilience4j-retry/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/retry/Retry.java#L171) which is only catching `RuntimeExceptions` whilst `ConnectException` is not a `RuntimeException`:

```
    ... decorateSupplier(Retry retry, Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return () -> {
            Retry.Context<T> context = retry.context();
            do try {
               ...
            } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
               ...
```

Look through the [`Retry.java`](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/438bf75c853567f54b7abda968028b15895105d5/resilience4j-retry/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/retry/Retry.java) and choose one that catches `Exception` for example [`decorateCheckedFunction`](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/438bf75c853567f54b7abda968028b15895105d5/resilience4j-retry/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/retry/Retry.java#L147), for example

```
  val registry = 
    RetryRegistry.of(RetryConfig.custom().maxAttempts(4).build())
  val retry = registry.retry("my")

  Retry.decorateCheckedFunction(retry, (x: Int) => {
    println(s"woohoo $x")
    throw new ConnectException("Test")
    42
  }).apply(1)
```

which outputs

```
woohoo 1
woohoo 1
woohoo 1
woohoo 1
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Test
```

Personally I use [softwaremill/retry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56257291/5205022)